# need example for awk command and awk within awk command in in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I need a simple working example that makes me understand

1, awk command in shell script.
2, awk withing awk command in shell script.

Comment: Without some idea of what it is you're trying to achieve, or what your current skill / knowledge level is, anything trying to 'make you understand' is going to be at best, a shot in the dark...

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, what have you tried so far and why has it not worked out?  If not, what are you actually trying to accomplish.  Be specific.

Comment: Get an awk tutorial and go through it. Try these things out and get back to the forum.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what the point is, but here's awk calling awk from within a shell script...

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd='BEGIN {print \"foo\"}'
echo foo |
awk "{ system( \"awk '$cmd'\" )}"
```

Comment: Hi William, I'm facing problem when compiling this program - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716325/problem-in-using-awk . kindly suggest your opinion

Comment: @Logeshwari The program there is not valid.  You do not have balanced backquotes.  Also, are you trying to use the value of var1 within the program that assigns to var1?  I think perhaps there are some lines missing from that snippet.