# problem in using awk

Tags: shell, awk

i couldn't solve this. when i execute this program i get the following error
" line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' "

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]; then
var1=`echo $a | awk -F"U" '\
{
var2=`echo $var1 | awk -F"a"
{print " "$2}'`
}\
fi
```

**Update:** from other, recently closed question

To be more specific, this is my project code

```
if [ "$FORMAT" = "java" ]; then
        cat $INPUT_FILE | awk -F":" '\
                /^$/ { print "" }\
                /^\/\/.*/ { print "     "$0}\
                /:string:/ { print "    public static final String "$1" = "$3";" }\
                /:char:/   { print "    public static final char "$1" = "$3";" }\

/:ullong:/ { print "    public static final long "$1" = "$3";" }\
                /:ulong:/  { print "    public static final int "$1" = "$3";" }\
                /:long:/   { print "    public static final int "$1" = "$3";" }\
        ' >> $CONST_FILE
fi;
```

Now i need to truncate $3 (this value is actually read from another file) into two parts(only for ullong). lets say

```
$3=1256985361455ULL
```

i need to truncate into 1256985361455 and ULL. (only when it is ullong)
please help me out in this issue.

i tried using another awk inside the the following, but ended up in chaos.

```
/:ullong:/ { print "    public static final long "$1" = "$3";" }\
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The above snippet makes little sense.

Comment: i need to truncate the occurence of 'U' first and then from the output of that first awk command i need o truncate the occurence of 'a'. i'm just trying to provide this as an example because i need to use the similar method method in my project

Comment: So what is your final output after "truncating" ? Do you mean removing all the "a"s and "U"s ? Please ask your question clearly, providing examples of output you want where necessary.

Comment: Use multiple pipes - see sample in my answer

Comment: In the body of your awk script, there's no need to put a continuation character (\\) at the end of every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect the value of $3 for the ullong records to be something like "1256985361455ULL" then

```
/:ullong:/ { 
    sub(/ULL$/, "", $3)
    print "    public static final long "$1" = "$3";" 
}
```

Comment: @Logeshwari, now it's time to accept some answers for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your quoting problem is because once you start a back-quoted command, it continues until the next back-quote.  This is your code as shown above, except I've removed the blank lines.

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]; then
var1=`echo $a | awk -F"U" '\
{
var2=`echo $var1 | awk -F"a"
{print " "$2}'`
}\
fi
```

(*Back-quotes '`` ` ``' are hard to show in in-line Markdown.*)

The line `var1=` line starts a back-quoted expression, which stops at the next unescaped back-quote, which is the one after `var2=`.  It then reads the rest of that line, and on the following line, encounters a single quote.  When it looks for the following single quote, there is none - so it reports an error.  You can demonstrate this is what goes on in steps:

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]; then
var1=`echo $a | awk -F"U" '\
{
var2=\`echo $var1 | awk -F"a"
{print " "$2}'`
}\
fi
```

The script above has an escape (backslash) before the back-quote after `var2=`, so now the command in back-quotes extends to the back-quote after the `print` line.  This still isn't valid shell; the line with `}\` combines with the `fi` to make a command name `}fi`, so you still get an unexpected EOF error - because the `fi` for the end of the `if` is missing.  Modify the script again:

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]; then
var1=`echo $a | awk -F"U" '\
{
var2=\`echo $var1 | awk -F"a"
{print " "$2}'`
#}\
fi
```

This comments out the close brace, and the shell script is now 'valid'; it is `awk`'s turn to start complaining about the invalid script it is given.

```
++ awk -FU '{
var2=`echo $var1 | awk -F"a"
{print " "$2}'
awk: syntax error at source line 2
 context is
     >>> var2=` <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 2
awk: illegal statement at source line 2
    missing }
```

Other people have given you roughly what you need as an answer.  I'd probably use Perl to do the splitting up (and I suspect I could lose the intermediate array `@x` if I spent enough time on it, producing a script of line noise):

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]
then var1=$(echo $a | perl -ne '@x=split /[aU]/; print "$x[1]\n"')
fi
```

However, you can also do it in one line with `awk`, thus:

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]
then var1=$(echo $a | awk -Fa '{sub("ULL","",$2); print $2}')
fi
```

This splits the input on the 'a' instead of the 'U'; it then removes the 'ULL' from the second field and prints it.  If you want to split on 'U', then you use:

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]
then var1=$(echo $a | awk -FU '{sub("[0-9]+a", "", $1); print $1}')
fi
```

The regular expression in the `sub` is marginally more complex this way.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but this slight re-write printed out the middle part of a (which is I think what you wanted)

```
> cat moo.sh
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
if [ "$b" = "2" ]; then
        var1=`echo $a | awk -F"U" '{print $1}'`
        var2=`echo $var1 | awk -F"a" '{print " "$2}'`
        echo $var2
fi
> sh moo.sh
1504606846976
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do shell commands inside `awk` except to make system calls. without you telling us what you are trying to achieve

```
#!/bin/bash
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2
case "$b" in
 2 ) 
    a=${a%U*}
    echo ${a#*a} # I assume you want to get 1504606846976
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=115292a1504606846976ULL
b=2

if [ "$b" = "2" ]; then
  var1=`echo $a | awk -F "U" '{print $1}' | awk -F "a" '{print $2}'`
fi
```

Comment: If `awk` needs to be used, there's no need to invoke 2 instances of it. you can either do a `sub/gsub/split` on `$1` in the first `awk` , or use `-F"[Ua]"`

Comment: @kurumi: No, but this illustrates how to do what he needs in a readable way, using only what the OP demonstrates an understanding of. `sed` would either way be the best choice for this IMO.