# problem in using awk

Tags: shell, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem in using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716325/problem-in-using-awk)

To be more specific, this is my project code

```
if [ "$FORMAT" = "java" ]; then
        cat $INPUT_FILE | awk -F":" '\
                /^$/ { print "" }\
                /^\/\/.*/ { print "     "$0}\
                /:string:/ { print "    public static final String "$1" = "$3";" }\
                /:char:/   { print "    public static final char "$1" = "$3";" }\

/:ullong:/ { print "    public static final long "$1" = "$3";" }\
                /:ulong:/  { print "    public static final int "$1" = "$3";" }\
                /:long:/   { print "    public static final int "$1" = "$3";" }\
        ' >> $CONST_FILE
fi;
```

Now i need to truncate $3 (this value is actually read from another file) into two parts(only for ullong). lets say

```
$3=1256985361455ULL
```

i need to truncate into 1256985361455 and ULL. (only when it is ullong)
please help me out in this issue.

i tried using another awk inside the the following, but ended up in chaos.

```
/:ullong:/ { print "    public static final long "$1" = "$3";" }\
```

Comment: please go edit your previous post and add this information there.

Comment: awk tip:  You do not need to cat the file.  'cat foo | awk ...' is best done with 'awk ... foo'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you just want to insert a space into $3?  Just use sub:

```
bash-3.2$ cat input
one two 123456789ULL
one two 123456789UL
bash-3.2$ awk '{ sub( /ULL$/, " ULL", $3 ); print }' input
one two 123456789 ULL
one two 123456789UL
```

Comment: hi.. not a space..i need to truncate ULL from the $3..

Comment: So make the replacement string empty.  ie, sub( /ULL$/, "", $3 )